# Mapnik, TileCache, Apache2 - Setup&Debug

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm trying to setup TileCache with Mapnik working on an Apache Server. Right now I don't see any tiles in my OpenLayers Framework in the webbrowser. I really ask myself where the problem is hidden.

a) Does anyone have a good debug strategie for working with these 3 components?

b) Anyone working with that and can give a little working sample setup. Maybe my confs are wrong or incomplete.

Thanks!